# comments extraction from youtube using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Python Selenium for comments extraction from youtube

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6NhKKl-iR0")
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//body'):
print elem.text
```

how to get comments?

Answer (score 1):

The comments are in the divs with the class `comment-renderer-text-content`

```
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="comment-renderer-text-content"]'):
    print elem.text
```

Which gives you:

```
great stuff man. question: why use selenium for this site when the data you're looking for is in the source code and could be scraped with requests/beautifulsoup? disclaimer: i'm commenting a year later so the source code may be different :)
Good question, if the data is in source you're right, selenium is overkill.  I use selenium when I find it quicker to not have to reverse engineer a site looking for sever calls which return json data that only exists inside the browser etc...  So the bottom line is if you're really crafty picking off JSON calls to the server and replicating that without needing to have the DOM built for you than it's a much better be to use BeautifulSoup or Python Requests.   However if you're creating for instance an automated program to automatically pin, like stuff on facebook etc... you will most likely not be able to pull that off very easily just using BeautifulSoup. 
Answered my questions very well.
Great job! I do have a questions though. What if the site is built in silverlight? Then I cannot see the Xpath of each element...
the first test was slow because of a slow loading adserver, you can see it in firefox at the bottom bar.
This is good stuff.
Clear and useful although i'm using java. Thx
YOU ARE BETTER THAN A PROFESSIONAL TEACHER MAN!!!.. 
thanks man
```

The comments are loaded dynamically so you might need to wait for the presecnce of the elements:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait(dr, x):
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x))
    )
    return element


from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6NhKKl-iR0")

for elem in wait(browser, '//div[@class="comment-renderer-text-content"]'):
    print elem.text
```

Comment: Is that because of a proxy problem. Could you please tell.

Comment: @VinayakumarR, you most likely just need to  wait, I edited the answer, the comments are loaded after the page loads

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, I executed your sample program but is is showing an error:TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: What version of selenium?

Comment: selenium version = 2.53.1 I am using windows 7 and python version 2.7.10

Comment: And your version of Firefox?  Also try increasing the wait time.

Comment: mozill firefox 44.0. Even i tried by increasing wait time, i am getting same error

Comment: Could you please tell in which platform you excited your program Windows or linux